# Как сделать изображение (блоки) адаптивными в плагине 3D THUMBNAIL HOVER EFFECTS?

Tags: плагин, css

Привет всем!

Как сделать изображение (блоки) адаптивными? То есть при уменьшении окна что бы уменьшалось (адаптировалось) соответственно изображение? Здесь [демо](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DHoverEffects/), здесь [исходники](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/18/3d-thumbnail-hover-effects/).

Прописываю в стилях к .view

```
{max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

Адаптируется только рамка. Изображение нет. Очень нужно помочь.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В примере, изображение у вас, как бэкграунд. Поэтому попробуйте задать правило  [background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size), НО надо учитывать, что это сработает только для браузеров, которые поддерживают это правило

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, почему когда задаю {max-width: 100%; height: auto;} картинка масштабируется только в хроме?

Comment: В других браузерах не адаптируется...

Comment: уже не нужно) сам решил)